# Eigenvectors of Laplacian matrix of path graph

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, graph-laplacian, tridiagonal-matrices

I would like to diagonalize the $N \times N$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1 & & & & & 0 \\ 
  -1 & 2 & -1 & & & & \\
  & -1 & 2 & -1 & & & \\
  & & & \ddots & & & \\
  & & & -1 & 2 & -1 & \\
  & & & & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
  0 & & & & & -1 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

By curve fitting, I managed to guess the eigenvalues to be of the form $2 - 2 \cos(\frac{k \pi}{N})$, with $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, N-1\}$. Any tips on how to get the eigenvectors?

Comment: Found an article with the solution by [Jiang](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/JiangJ.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

The components of the eigenvector associated with the $k^{th}$ eingenvalue are
$$
v_k(u)=\cos\left[\frac{\pi k}{N} \Big(u - \frac{1}{2}\Big)\right]\quad k\in \{0,1,…,N−1\}.
$$
You can find the proof in these [lectures notes by Prof. Daniel Spielman](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/2009/), precisely in the [second lecture, lemma 2.4.5, pp. 2.5-2.6](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/2009/lect02-09.pdf).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2050884)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).